# Why don't enums result in infinite recursions?

Tags: java, enums

In java enums are declared as follows:

```
enum Fruits{
BANANA,
ORANGE,
APPLE
}
```

In the example, the enums declared are of the same type as the class. So, when I create an instance of the enum Fruits:

```
Fruits example = Fruits.ORANGE
```

it means that an instance of the enum fruits is created which then goes on to create instances for each enum. Given that each enum in fruits is of the type fruits they go on to create further instances... and so on resulting in infinte recursion. Am I missing something ?

Comment: No, the declaration of the enum creates the instances; it's the only code construct that _can_ create enum instances.  Your assignment merely references the already-existing instance.

Comment: Enum instances are static singletons. They're created once and only once.

Comment: The [`Enum` Javadoc for `valueOf(Class, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)) notes *All the constants of an enum type can be obtained by calling the implicit `public static T[] values()` method of that type.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
enum Fruits{
BANANA,
ORANGE,
APPLE
}
```

is effectively the same as

```
class Fruits{
  static final Fruits BANANA = new Fruits("BANANA", 0);
  static final Fruits ORANGE = new Fruits("ORANGE", 1);
  static final Fruits APPLE = new Fruits("APPLE", 2);

  private Fruits(String name, int ordinal) {
    super(name, ordinal);
  }
}
```

with a little bit of extra helper stuff. Try decompiling an enum class (e.g. with `javap`) and you can see that it's like this.

As such, when you write:

```
Fruits example = Fruits.ORANGE
```

you're not creating a new instance of the class: you're just referring to a static field.

Answer (score 0):

But remember that as they are singletons, changing attributes of one type field changes all "instances" of that field.

```java
    enum Fruit {
       APPLE, ORANGE;
       private String color = "red";

       public String getColor() {
          return color;
       }

       public void setColor(String color) {
          this.color = color;
       }
    }


    Fruit apple = Fruit.APPLE;
    Fruit otherApple = Fruit.APPLE;


    System.out.println(apple.getColor()); // prints red
    System.out.println(otherApple.getColor()); // prints red

    apple.setColor("green");  // change apples color

    System.out.println(pple.getColor());  // prints green
    System.out.println(otherApple.getColor()); // prints green
```